# SELECT when 2 conditions are satisfied per ID sql

Tags: mysql, sql

My example data

```
     ID        State 
     11        3
     11        3
     12        3
     12        6
     12        7
     13        3
     13        6
     13        7
     14        4
     14        4
     14        6
     15        3
     15        3
     16        3
     16        6
     16        7
     17        3
     17        7
```

I only want to SELECT the IDs that have a 3 & 6 OR 7. So in this example the ID 12, 13, 16 and 17 are selected (since these have a 3 and a 6 OR 7). I tried to work with

WHERE state IN (3, 6, 7). Hence this only selects cases that have either one for the 3 states, yet I want a solution in which I can say select when ID has at least a 3 and 6 OR 7. So the combinations of 3 & 6, 3 & 7 and 3 & 6 & 7 are selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below logic using GROUP BY and HAVING to achieve your required output. Although you do not mentioned your database name, this following logic should work for most of the RDBMS.

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4c6eabb85163a2bd1a0626e15cdabdd0)

```
SELECT ID 
FROM your table
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN State IN (3,6) THEN State ELSE NULL END) = 2
OR COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN State IN (7) THEN State ELSE NULL END) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an subselect. Example:

```
select ID, STATE
FROM [TABLENAME]
WHERE ID in
 (select ID FROM [TABLENAME] WHERE state IN (3, 6, 7))
```

You can find detailed info here: 
https://www.w3resource.com/sql/subqueries/understanding-sql-subqueries.php

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun you could group_concat and do a bit of string manipulation to get the result you want

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;

CREATE TABLE T (
ID int,       State int);
insert into t values
(     11     ,   3),
(     11     ,   3),
(     12     ,   3),
(     12     ,   6),
(     12     ,   7),
(     13     ,   3),
(     13     ,   6),
(     13     ,   7),
(     14     ,   4),
(     14     ,   4),
(     14     ,   6),
(     15     ,   3),
(     15     ,   3),
(     16     ,   3),
(     16     ,   5),
(     16     ,   7),
(     17     ,   3),
(     17     ,   7),
(     18     ,   2),
(     18     ,   3),
(     18     ,   5),
(     18     ,   6),
(     19     ,   7),
(     19     ,   3),
(     19     ,   5)
;

select id,
             group_concat(distinct case when state in (3,6,7) then state end order by state asc)
from t
group by id
having substring_index(group_concat(distinct case when state in (3,6,7) then state end order by state asc),',',2) = '3,6' or
         concat(
         substring_index(group_concat(distinct case when state in (3,6,7) then state end order by state asc),',',1) 
         ,',',
         substring_index(group_concat(distinct case when state in (3,6,7) then state end order by state asc),',',-1) 
         ) = '3,7'       
;

+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id   | group_concat(distinct case when state in (3,6,7) then state end order by state asc) |
+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   12 | 3,6,7                                                                               |
|   13 | 3,6,7                                                                               |
|   16 | 3,7                                                                                 |
|   17 | 3,7                                                                                 |
|   18 | 3,6                                                                                 |
|   19 | 3,7                                                                                 |
+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.002 sec)
```

The distinct in the group_concat removes duplicate states and the order by  forces the state into ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

You can group by `id` and set the conditions in the `having` clause:

```
select id
from tablename
where state in (3, 6, 7)
group by id
having sum(state = 3) and sum(state in (6, 7))
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dQMkXbcW7qw58iDCKaJD4Z/7).

If you want these `id`s not to have any other states then:

```
select id
from tablename
group by id
having sum(state = 3) and sum(state in (6, 7))
and not sum(state not in (3, 6, 7))
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dQMkXbcW7qw58iDCKaJD4Z/8).

Results:

```
| id  |
| --- |
| 12  |
| 13  |
| 16  |
| 17  |
```